# How to Init start values in DropDown using Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

Six
    Five
    Three
    One

And I have controller:

```
    DBEntity context = new DBEntity(); // My EntityModel
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetStartValues()
    {
        var b = context.MyTable.ToList();
        return Json(ConvertObj(b));
    }
    private object ConvertObj(List<MyTable> lst)
    {
        var list = new object[lst.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
        {
            list[i] = new { value = lst[i].MyValue, name = lst_meals[i].MyText };
        }
        return list;
    }
```

My question is: How to Init this values as start values **using jQuery**.
I can use solution like this:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = context.MyTable.ToList()
        return View(model);
    }
```

In .aspx

```
   <select id="myDropdown" name="myDropdown"> 
   <% foreach(var obj in Model.MyTableList) {%>
   <option value="<%: obj.MyValue %>"><%: obj.MyText %></option>
   <% } %>
```

But I want use Jquery for this)

I want to populate the drop down list by making an asynchronous call to a service, but I don't know what event I have to use... If I trying to populate drop down:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $.post("/GetStartValues/", { }, function (data) {
       populateDropdown($("#[id*='myDropdown']"), data);
     });
 }

 function populateDropdown(select, data) {
        select.html(''); //clear all items
        $.each(data, function (id, option) {
            select.append($('<option></option>').val(option.value).html(option.name));
        });
 }
```

But it isn't working. I want to insert values into DropDown using Jquery request as soon as page is loaded.

Comment: How do you want to use jQuery?  Do you want to populate the drop down list by making an asynchronous call to a service, or do you want to use jQuery to read an element that has the data and loop through it to populate the dropdown list?  Can you please update your post with your requirements?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your controller returning the correct Ajax?

I'm not sure what your ConvertObj does but assuming you are returning the Ajax correctly, then this jQuery should work.

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/GetStartValues/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#myDropdown').html('');
                for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $('#myDropdown').append($('<option></option>').attr('value', data[0].value).text(data[0].name));
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank for answer) It works=) 
(but I use my function to input values into DropDown)
 function populateDropdown(select, data) {
...
});

Sorry((( I didn't write function ConvertObj. I'll do it in few minutes.